# generating RSS feed...django/python

Tags: python, django, rss

I'm not using regular model, so can't use Django's syndication framework. So, i did used the low-level syndication util called feedgenerator to generate RSS feeds like shown below.

```
feed = feedgenerator.Rss201rev2Feed(title=_("Feed by %s") % user.username,
        link="http://%s" % DOMAIN_NAME,
        description=_("RSS Feed provided by something.com"),
        language=user.language, 
        author_name=user.full_name, 
        feed_url="something")

    for note in ObjectModel.published_objects.filter(user=user):
        feed.add_item(title=note.title,
            link="",
            pubDate=note.created,
            description=note.note)
    response = HttpResponse(feed.writeString('UTF-8'), mimetype='application/rss+xml')
    return response
```

However, I couldn't find good example how i can return this as Response type.

```
response = HttpResponse(feed.writeString('UTF-8'), mimetype='application/rss+xml')
```

Apparently, Above code seems not right cause the browser does not recognizes as RSS feed. Could someone tell me what I should do to fix this problem?

Comment: http://cdn.memegenerator.net/instances/400x/21651590.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just working fine. Was recognizable by browser.